# Data on Argentina car industry

Tags: data-request

I am working on a paper for university about the car industry in Argentina.
I found a lot of data, but I cannot find any data about the turnover, profits and part of the GDP of this industry (Neither for each one one the companies) between 2014 and at least 2000 maybe more if possible.

The national office of statistics (INDEC) does not seems to have it, neither the ADEFA (Association of car constructors).

Does anyone have a good data website about this industry in Argentina?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ADEFA website](http://www.adefa.org.ar/es/estadisticas-anuarios) does have information on sales, disaggregated by company, market (internal/export), and for very year since 1959. For example:

[image]

This data is [here](http://www.adefa.org.ar/upload/anuarios/anuario2015/3.pdf). Disaggregation by company and market is [here](http://www.adefa.org.ar/upload/anuarios/anuario2015/5.pdf).

ADEFA does not provide data on profits thought. As you can see from the latter link, all companies are multinationals with subsidiaries in Argentina (e.g. Toyota Argentina S.A. where "S.A." stands for *Sociedad Anónima*, meaning PLC). As such, they provide annual statements to the local tax authorities, including profits. They should also publish annual reports to their investors (e.g. Toyota 2014 [here](https://www.toyotacfa.com.ar/uploads/politica/Memoria%20y%20Balance%20Consolidado%20Anual%20(Completo)%20al%2031%20Dic%202014.pdf); see profits in page 8). And official government organisations also make these statement public (e.g. [here](https://www.boletinoficial.gob.ar/#!DetalleSegunda/A635012/null)). In other words, all the data must be available online. You just need to google something like "name of company memoria anual 20XX", where *memoria anual* stands for annual financial report, for year 20XX.

Whether the data is **systematically** available free of charge, I doubt it. Normally consultancy companies, investment banks and other financial firms produce compilations and analysis of this data for their clients (know this from first hand, when worked at Deutsche Bank). Unless you have access to one of those, you will have to compile the data yourself. At least there are just a few car companies, so this should not take you long.

PS: beware of over/under reported utilities due to [transfer pricing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_pricing) though.